# How to use Replace an unknown length of characters in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How do I replace a series of periods in SQL server ?  If a field has more than one period next to each other, then I want to replace them with asterisks. The problem is that I want to do this with 2,3,4... asterisks.  I'll never know how many periods there will be.  Some users enter two and some enter ten.

**When to replace or delete:**

- When there is more than one period next to each other I want to replace them with asterisks.
- When a period is the only character in the field I want to delete it.

My Select statement is as follows:

```
SELECT CAST(QTEXT + ' ' AS VARCHAR(MAX))FROM MYTABLE WHERE CMPNO = @compID AND Q5XY = 'NDT' FOR XML PATH ('')
```

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data and output

Comment: Is this a one off job or something you want to do regularly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the periods pairwise and adjust for the case that there are an odd number of periods:

```
 select replace ( replace (replace (qtext, '..', '**'), '*.', '**' ), '.', '')
   from ...
      ;
```

Single periods (= without adjacent periods) have remained in place after the first two replacements and are deleted by the third `replace` call.

Comment: Nice.  I'm testing now.  I'll be back to mark as answer once I pass all tests. :)